# Find the general solution of the ordinary differential equation. Verify your solution. $(x^2-y^2 )dx+(y^2-2xy)dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution of the ordinary differential equation. Verify your solution.

$(x^2-y^2)dx+(y^2-2xy)dy=0$

To me this looks more like an exact differential equation than an ordinary differential equation since it would fit the form $M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$ where $M(x,y)dx = (x^2-y^2)dx$ and $N(x,y)dy = (y^2-2xy)dy$

The only other thought I had would be to try to factor out the left-hand side if that would work, any tips appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(x^2-y^2)dx+(y^2-2xy)dy=0$$
Yes it's exact:
$$x^2dx-y^2dx+y^2dy-xdy^2=0$$
$$x^2dx-(y^2dx+xdy^2)+y^2dy=0$$
$$x^2dx-d(xy^2)+y^2dy=0$$
Integrate:
$$x^3-3xy^2+y^3=C$$
$$F(x,y)=C$$

You can also find $F$ by integration:
$$F=\int M dx=\int x^2-y^2dx=\dfrac {x^3}3-y^2x+C(y)$$
$$F=\int Ndy=\int y^2-2xy dy=\dfrac {y^3}3-xy^2+C(x)$$
You deduce that 
$$F(x,y)=\dfrac {x^3+y^3}3-xy^2=C$$

Comment: How would you go about trying to solve for y at this point while having the $-3xy^2$ term?

Comment: We call this an implicit form...not all solutions to DE can be expressed in explicit form @Tunifish17

Comment: Makes sense, thank you for clarifying.  When it comes to simplifying $(y^2dx+xdy^2)$ by removing the d, why wouldn't it become $d(2xy^2)$ ?

Comment: It comes with practice that you recognize easily the form..;Otherwise you can also differentiate $2xy^2$ and get the same result...You can also find $F(x,y)=c$ by integrating M with respect to x and $N$ with respect to y...it gives the same result as mine.  @Tunifish17

Comment: I added some lines I hope it's more clear @Tunifish17

Comment: Those extra lines did help @Aryadeva, I appreciated all of your help today!

Comment: you're welcome @Tunifish17

Answer (score 0):

The ODE is homogeneous so making $y = \mu x$ we have

$$
\mu' x + \mu = \frac{\mu^2-1}{\mu^2-2\mu}
$$

which is separable then

$$
\frac{d\mu}{ \frac{\mu^2-1}{\mu^2-2\mu}-\mu} = \frac{dx}{x}
$$

or

$$
-\frac 13\ln\left(\mu^3-3\mu^2+1\right) = C_0+\ln x
$$

or

$$
\mu^3-3\mu^2+1 = \frac{C_1}{x^3}
$$

etc.